# Error "Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI" in mod_hfs_apple after updating mac os x from 10.8.3 to 10.8.4

Tags: macos, apache

I have set up a local development machine on my laptop with Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15. Everything was working fine until I upgraded OS X. I kept getting a 403 error whenever I tried accessing my localhost server. I checked my apache error_log and found these entries.

```
[Mon Jun 24 14:48:30 2013] [error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Users/Eugene/Sites/index.html, wants: /\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/Eugene/Sites/\xe2\x80\x9d/
[Mon Jun 24 14:48:30 2013] [error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Users/Eugene/Sites/index.php, wants: /\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/Eugene/Sites/\xe2\x80\x9d/
[Mon Jun 24 14:48:31 2013] [error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Users/Eugene/Sites/index.html, wants: /\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/Eugene/Sites/\xe2\x80\x9d/
[Mon Jun 24 14:48:31 2013] [error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Users/Eugene/Sites/index.html, wants: /\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/Eugene/Sites/\xe2\x80\x9d/
[Mon Jun 24 14:48:31 2013] [error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Users/Eugene/Sites/index.php, wants: /\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/Eugene/Sites/\xe2\x80\x9d/
[Mon Jun 24 14:48:31 2013] [error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Users/Eugene/Sites/favicon.ico, wants: /\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/Eugene/Sites/\xe2\x80\x9d/
```

I managed to find a way around this by commenting out this line in httpd.conf

```
#LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
```

However, I realise that this is just a temporary hack and need to find a solution for this problem. Can someone help me out?

It seems like the mod_hfs_apple2.c file is adding \xe2\x80\x9c (“) and \xe2\x80\x9d (”) around the file names. Unicode characters got from [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal). This makes the request different from the DocumentRoot directory.

For example in my httpd.conf I have this

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/Username/Sites"
```

and this is the error I find after running `tail error_log`

```
[Mon Nov 18 19:51:35 2013] [error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Users/Username/Sites/index.php, wants: /\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/Username/Sites/\xe2\x80\x9d/
```

The mod_hfs_apple2.c can be found [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/apache_mod_hfs_apple/). Am not sure which version ships with maverick my current OS.

For now I keep the hack.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error too and found this:

http://software.techassistbox.com/error-mis-cased-uri-or-unacceptable-unicode-in-uri-in-modhfsapple-after-updating-mac-os-x-from-1083-to-1084_52942.html

In sum, comment out this line in httpd.conf:

```
#LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
```

It's a hack but it works.

Comment: awesome answer. worked for me. This should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises typically when a directory named in the Apache config has characters which either contain Unicode or differ in case from the actual name in the filesystem. Directory names can occur in a bunch of different places including `<Directory></Directory>`tags, and in your case, the DocumentRoot directive.

The culprit in your case would appear to be whatever application you're using to edit your httpd.conf. It is replacing your double quotes with smart quotes. Apache then sees not a quoted string, but an unquoted string which happens to begin and end with some unicode. Eventually this gets passed onto mod_hfs_apple which complains because it can't match it to an actual path on the filesystem.

The fix: edit your httpd.conf only in an application which makes it obvious when you're stepping outside the ASCII character set. If you're using BBEdit, make sure the preference "Use typographer's quotes" is not enabled. Secondly, make sure that the case of any directory specified in the config matches the case in the actual filesystem.

Comment: I tried editing it using many editors and I was still stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/Username/Sites"
```

Use:

```
DocumentRoot /Users/Username/Sites
```

Removing the quotation marks fixed the issue for me